# Middle Mouse Button not working in blender

Tags: 3d-view, timeline

I have a Three button mouse. But still I cannot use the middle mouse button to rotate and pan the view in the navigation port. I also cannot set the start and end points of the output in the timeline using middle mouse button.

Answer (score 2):

Things to try:

1. Check that the mouse works and that no other software steals the input
2. Backup your settings (optional but a good idea)
3. Reset Blenders factory settings

Comment: i did everything. i also tried blender to install in my another pc. but same issue there. is there a specific mouse company or driver that blender needs